# Python package import another package on same level

Tags: python

My current structure:

```
+- libs/ -+- lib1/ -+- __init__.py
|         |         |
|         |         +- classA.py
|         |         |
|         |         +- classB.py
|         |
|         +- lib2/ -+- __init__.py
|         |
|         +- __init__.py
|
+- script.py
```

In `script.py` I do `from libs import lib1` where in `lib1/__init__.py` I will conditionally import either `classA` or `classB` and use it as singleton for entire run.

In both `classA` and `classB` I need to use `lib2` which I import as `from libs import lib2`.

Everything works perfect until the point where in `lib2/__init__.py` I need to call some methods of singleton of `lib1` and it fails to import it with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/script", line 5, in <module>
    from libs import lib1
  File "/home/vagrant/sync/src/libs/lib1/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import classA
  File "/home/vagrant/sync/src/libs/lib1/classA.py", line 5, in <module>
    from libs import lib2
  File "/home/vagrant/sync/src/libs/lib2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from libs import lib1
ImportError: No module named libs
```

Not quite sure why from `lib1/classA.py` I can import neighboring `lib2` just fine, but at the same time from `lib2/__init__.py` cannot import neighboring `lib1`? Is there something I am missing about how imports work?

Comment: So lib2 needs lib1 to function, and lib1 needs lib2 to function? That sounds like a chicken-and-egg problem or *circular dependency*. There [are some tricks](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm#circular-imports) you could try, but refactoring your code so that dependencies are no longer circular is better.

Comment: @WanderNauta I could understand if it was complaining about circular dependency. But it just can't find the package at all o_O

Comment: do you have an `__init__.py` in folder containing script.py and libs ?

Comment: @ahieulle You can see in the structure that I do have it in libs, but not in top level (and why would need it on top level?)